# footnote counter, would like to restart from '1' each page

Tags: numbering, footnotes, counters

I would like the footnote counter to automatically restart from '1' for each page of my document.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc

Comment: I like your answer. It's short and correct. I'd like to see some minor explanation what exactly that package does

Comment: I suspect the @Leo is not coming back; I'd really appreciate if *someone* added a sentence or two of explanation.

Comment: From the documentation: "This option resets footnote numbering for each page of the document.  It needs at least two passes to do this correctly (though it comes as close as possible on the first pass).  You generally have to make two passes with LATEX anyway, to get the cross-references right, so an additional pass for this purpose shouldn’t cause any additional problem.  The option includes code to report that ‘Label(s) may have changed’, which will help the poor user to realise that (yet) another run is
in order."

Comment: This made all my footnote marks link to the first page. The numbering worked correctly, though. `\usepackage{perpage} \MakePerPage{footnote}` worked right in both regards.

Comment: This answer is perfect. (It is not clear what "minor explanation" might be needed here).

Comment: @SU3 In this case try loading `footmisc` before `hyperref`.

Answer (score 16):

Using the counter `page` will produce wrong results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\@newctr{footnote}[page]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{bla}

\blindtext\footnote{bla}

\blindtext\footnote{bla}

\blindtext\footnote{bla}

\blindtext\footnote{bla}

\end{document}
```

Instead, you should use either the package `footmisc` with the `perpage` option or the following code:

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Comment: For some reason the accepted answer did not work for me (probably some package conflict) but this one did. The perpage package used as shown in the last two lines of this answer is definitely a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

One just needs to make the counter `footnote` "subcounter" of the counter `page` (as in `\newcounter{subcounter}[counter]`). The only problem is lack of `\renewcounter` command, so one has to use

```
\makeatletter
\@newctr{footnote}[page]
\makeatother
```

*Update:* as [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) points out, the counter `page` is unreliable and one has to use e.g.

```
 \usepackage{perpage}
 \MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Comment: Using the counter `page` will produce wrong results (see example in my answer).

Comment: This should probably stay as a warning to the unwary?