# Trouble with hyperref when resetting the counter for equations (specifically with the align environment)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, counters

I am trying to reset a counter to zero; however `hyperref` tries to reference previous equations. I am using:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

And if I have labels in say `align` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=1
\label{eq:a} \\
y=2
\label{eq:b}
\end{align}
Eq.~\eqref{eq:a}.
Reset counter
\newpage
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
x=10
\label{eq:c} \\
y=20
\label{eq:d} 
\end{align}
Now trying to refer to third equation Eq.~\eqref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

If I now `\ref{eq:c}`, the `hyperref` package will point me back to `eq:a` (in text, they both have the same number).

Is there a way to fix this without manually stepping a new counter you make? I.e. can you fix it without doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=1
\label{eq:a} \\
y=2
\label{eq:b}
\end{align}
Eq.~\eqref{eq:a}.
Reset counter
\newpage
%% \setcounter{equation}{0}                                %Commented out line
\newcounter{newequation}                                   %Added line
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{newequation}}          %Added line
\stepcounter{newequation}                                  %Added line
\begin{align}
x=10
\label{eq:c} \\ 
\stepcounter{newequation}                                  %Added line
y=20
\label{eq:d} 
\end{align}
Now trying to refer to third equation Eq.~\eqref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example please? It makes things easier if we have some complete code to copy and play with.

Comment: Does that work @MarkS.Everitt?

Comment: Thanks. It may seem like a petty thing, but it lowers the mental barrier against taking up a question. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To produce correct references, you have to make the counter values unique to `hyperref`. To do so, you can introduce a parent counter `myequation`: Each time this counter is increased, the counter `equation` is reset. Like this, `hyperref` can take into account both the value of `myequation` and `equation` to produce the correct hyperlink.

In order to do this, add the following code to your document after having loaded `hyperref`:

```
\newcounter{myequation}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{myequation}
\makeatother
```

Resetting the equation counter is done by stepping `myequation`, so use `\stepcounter{myequation}` instead of `\setcounter{equation}{0}`.

#### Full example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{myequation}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{myequation}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=1
\label{eq:a} \\
y=2
\label{eq:b}
\end{align}
Eq.~\eqref{eq:a}.
Reset counter
\newpage
\stepcounter{myequation}
\begin{align}
x=10
\label{eq:c} \\
y=20
\label{eq:d} 
\end{align}
Now trying to refer to third equation Eq.~\eqref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the `page` counter may produce wrong results. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1661/510) answer for an example.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks for pointing that out, I removed the corresponding part from my answer.

Comment: This can be automated using `\usepackage{etoolbox}\preto\align{\stepcounter}{myequation}}`.

Comment: This hyperref option `hypertexnames=false` does few magics too. source: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6102/18678)