# Question on endless footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I'm currently using the package:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

However, after adding quite of few of these footnotes in my text, I'm now getting the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Counter too large.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.210 ...tween supernovae Type II events\footnote{
>                                               One recent notable superno...
> ```

Essentially, the count for my number of footnotes has exceeded the number of symbols in the `fnsymbol` package.

Would anyone know how to reset the count after the number of symbols used has been exceeded?

P.S. I really like adding lots of footnotes!

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1656) an acceptable solution?

Comment: @campa Acceptable, but how would I modify this to reset after say 'x' number of pages? (x=5,10) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a standard class, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\footnote}
  {\stepcounter\@mpfn}
  {\stepcounter\@mpfn\check@overflow\@mpfn}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\check@overflow}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@mpfn}{footnote}=\z@
    \ifnum\value{footnote}>9
      \setcounter{footnote}{1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}

x\footnote{1}
x\footnote{2}
x\footnote{3}
x\footnote{4}
x\footnote{5}
x\footnote{6}
x\footnote{7}
x\footnote{8}
x\footnote{9}
x\footnote{10}
x\footnote{11}
x\footnote{12}
x\footnote{13}

\end{document}
```

But your readers won't be happy: besides lots of footnotes, you lose the ability of distinguishing between them. Use numbers.

Footnote symbols are good if there's at most to or three footnotes in a page and not on every page. All other usages should be with numbers.

[image]

Comment: Accepted late last night on the phone app, but wanted to say thank you for your help in person. Many thanks. Worked perfectly.