# Reset footnote counter by section with footmisc

Tags: footnotes, counters, footmisc

I would like to reset my footnote counter for every section in my article, and I am using the `footmisc` package. I have seen the `perpage` option, and similarly there are questions on how to achieve this for chapters, but I would like the equivalent for sections, and am struggling to find an applicable solution.

Currently my preamble includes (among other things):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

Similar questions:

- [footnote counter, would like to restart from '1' each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/footnote-counter-would-like-to-restart-from-1-each-page)
- [How to reset footnote numbering at \chapter* and at frontmatter chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/how-to-reset-footnote-numbering-at-chapter-and-at-frontmatter-chapters)

Comment: `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}\makeatother` perhaps?

Comment: `\usepackage{chngctnr} \counterwithin*{footnote}{section}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}
\makeatother
```

or
    `\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}`

The `*` prevents `\counterwithin` from prepending the section number to the `footnote` number.

The first version does not need a package, the second one requires the `chngcntr` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}



\usepackage{chngcntr}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
A stupid footnote\footnote{Some stuff} and another one here\footnote{Boring footnote}

\clearpage
\section{Another important section}
A stupid footnote\footnote{Some stuff} and another one here\footnote{Boring footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried \counterwithin*{footnote}{section} and \counterwithin*{footnote}{chapter}  but it doesn't seem to work with footmisc, even with \usepackage{chngcntr}.  The numbering starts at every chapter.

Comment: @skan: Well, what do you expect? That's precisely the purpose of `\counterwithin` -- providing a master counter for some slave counter. If you say `\counterwithin{footnote}{chapter}` the footnote counter will be reset with every new chapter.

Comment: I would like a continuous counter through all chapter and sections. I don't wan't it to reset at every chapter.  But I have tried with and without \usepackage{chngcntr}    
 and/or \counterwithin*{footnote}{section} with no luck, the counter starts again at every chapter.

Comment: @skan: Have you tried `\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}` already? ;-)

Comment: Now it works, thanks.

Comment: (+1) for your remark (\counterwithout) because I can change within the document and alternate between \counterwithin and \counterwithout which is not possible with \counterwithin*.